# How can I debug this SIGSEGV crash in iOS that shows no lines of my code?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, crash-dumps

I have my app live on the iOS App Store with BugSense in it, which uploads user crashes and symbolicates the reports automatically. This report has already been symbolicated, but obviously it doesn't matter because there are no lines in the report that point to my code.

So my question, what am I supposed to do with a crash like this? How can I even begin to track down how this crash occurred?

By the way, my code has hundreds of thousands of lines in it with over 150 different code files... I can't just "run it in the debugger and see if you can reproduce" without doing a full huge test pass. I need a quicker way to track this down if possible:

```
0libobjc.A.dylib 0x37c00ba6 objc_msgSend_stret + 5
1UIKit 0x30082e7d <redacted> + 292
2UIKit 0x2ffb7641 <redacted> + 372
3QuartzCore 0x2fbedbb9 <redacted> + 100
4QuartzCore 0x2fbd743f <redacted> + 1854
5QuartzCore 0x2fcb0425 <redacted> + 52
6QuartzCore 0x2fbd6cf3 <redacted> + 82
7QuartzCore 0x2fbd699b <redacted> + 1106
8QuartzCore 0x2fbba67d <redacted> + 208
9QuartzCore 0x2fbba315 <redacted> + 24
10QuartzCore 0x2fbb9d1f <redacted> + 230
11QuartzCore 0x2fbb9b2f <redacted> + 314
12QuartzCore 0x2fc0e825 <redacted> + 516
13IOMobileFramebuffer 0x3283b76d <redacted> + 104
14IOKit 0x2e4a6a75 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 248
15CoreFoundation 0x2d784e21 <redacted> + 136
16CoreFoundation 0x2d78f9df <redacted> + 34
17CoreFoundation 0x2d78f97b <redacted> + 346
18CoreFoundation 0x2d78e14f <redacted> + 1398
19CoreFoundation 0x2d6f8c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
20CoreFoundation 0x2d6f8a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21GraphicsServices 0x3241f283 GSEventRunModal + 138
22UIKit 0x2ff9c049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
23Movies 0x00116497 main (main.m:14) + 136343
```

Any ideas??

By the way, this is why `<redacted>` is shown:

https://bugsense.zendesk.com/entries/27780998-I-ve-uploaded-the-dSYM-but-Istill-see-most-lines-in-crash-reports-with-redacted-Am-I-doing-something

Comment: It seems that your stack trace has not been symbolicated. (And it seems to be confirmed by your given link)
You should import your crashs logs in the XCode that made the right archive, it should be able to symbolicate this

Comment: Unfortunately: https://bugsense.zendesk.com/entries/27821933-Can-I-download-the-raw-crash-report-to-symbolicate-it-using-Xcode-

Comment: There is a little trick you can use.
1) Export a crash log from XCode
2) Delete it from Xcode
3) Open it with a text editor and replace the stack trace with this one
4) Import it back in Xcode

Comment: That won't really work always (rather only luckily), since the binary images section contain important load addresses, which are not identical for each crash. In addition you would have to make sure that the crash report uses the same iOS version and cpu architecture.

Comment: i can not really see your hole crashlog, but you can try use this http://sourceforge.net/p/umsservices/wiki/Home/ to symbolicate it.
if it is not working, i'll try to symbolicate the log for you if you send me with the dSYM file (just to see where the linked tool fails)